# How to do an inverse `range`, i.e. create a compact range based on a set of numbers?

Tags: python, numbers, range, pcre

Python has a `range` method, which allows for stuff like:

```
>>> range(1, 6)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

What I’m looking for is kind of the opposite: take a list of numbers, and return the start and end.

```
>>> magic([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
[1, 5] # note: 5, not 6; this differs from `range()`
```

This is easy enough to do for the above example, but **is it possible to allow for gaps or multiple ranges as well, returning the range in a PCRE-like string format?** Something like this:

```
>>> magic([1, 2, 4, 5])
['1-2', '4-5']
>>> magic([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
['1-5']
```

**Edit:** I’m looking for a Python solution, but I welcome working examples in other languages as well. It’s more about figuring out an elegant, efficient algorithm. Bonus question: is there any programming language that has a built-in method for this?

Comment: I have a suspicion that there's no better way than iterating through the list, which is easy to write on your own.

Comment: @trutheality Me too, hence this question. I’m hoping there’s an _elegant_ solution that I’m missing here. Fingers crossed!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A nice trick to simplify the code is to look at the difference of each element of the sorted list and its index:

```
a = [4, 2, 1, 5]
a.sort()
print [x - i for i, x in enumerate(a)]
```

prints

```
[1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Each run of the same number corresponds to a run of consecutive numbers in `a`.  We can now use `itertools.groupby()` to extract these runs.  Here's the complete code:

```
from itertools import groupby

def sub(x):
    return x[1] - x[0]

a = [5, 3, 7, 4, 1, 2, 9, 10]
ranges = []
for k, iterable in groupby(enumerate(sorted(a)), sub):
     rng = list(iterable)
     if len(rng) == 1:
         s = str(rng[0][1])
     else:
         s = "%s-%s" % (rng[0][1], rng[-1][1])
     ranges.append(s)
print ranges
```

printing

```
['1-5', '7', '9-10']
```

Comment: Nice! One (stupid) "problem" is the `list` call, which means you end up copying all the elements of the list in chunks unnecessarily, which doesn't matter at all in 99% of cases but can be avoided by using something like the `rangestr` function from my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Sort numbers, find consecutive ranges (remember RLE compression?).

Something like this:

```
input = [5,7,9,8,6, 21,20, 3,2,1, 22,23, 50]

output = []
first = last = None # first and last number of current consecutive range
for item in sorted(input):
  if first is None:
    first = last = item # bootstrap
  elif item == last + 1: # consecutive
    last = item # extend the range
  else: # not consecutive
    output.append((first, last)) # pack up the range
    first = last = item
# the last range ended by iteration end
output.append((first, last))

print output
```

Result: `[(1, 3), (5, 9), (20, 23), (50, 50)]`. You figure out the rest :)

Comment: `50-50` should just be `50`, but I think I can handle that myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I thought you might like my generalised clojure solution.

```
(def r [1 2 3 9 10])

(defn successive? [a b]
  (= a (dec b)))

(defn break-on [pred s]
  (reduce (fn [memo n]
            (if (empty? memo)
              [[n]]
              (if (pred (last (last memo)) n)
                (conj (vec (butlast memo))
                      (conj (last memo) n))
                (conj memo [n]))))
          []
          s))

(break-on successive? r)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of elegant but also kind of disgusting, depending on your point of view. :)

```
import itertools

def rangestr(iterable):
    end = start = iterable.next()
    for end in iterable:
        pass
    return "%s" % start if start == end else "%s-%s" % (start, end)

class Rememberer(object):
    last = None

class RangeFinder(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.o = Rememberer()

    def __call__(self, x):
        if self.o.last is not None and x != self.o.last + 1:
            self.o = Rememberer()
        self.o.last = x
        return self.o

def magic(iterable):
    return [rangestr(vals) for k, vals in
            itertools.groupby(sorted(iterable), RangeFinder())]


>>> magic([5,7,9,8,6, 21,20, 3,2,1, 22,23, 50])
['1-3', '5-9', '20-23', '50']
```

Explanation: it uses [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the sorted elements together by a key, where the key is a `Rememberer` object. The `RangeFinder` class keeps a `Rememberer` object as long as a consecutive bunch of items belongs to the same range block. Once you've passed out of a given block, it replaces the `Rememberer` so that the key won't compare equal and `groupby` will make a new group. As `groupby` walks over the sorted list, it passes the elements one-by-one into `rangestr`, which constructs the string by remembering the first and the last element and ignoring everything in between.

Is there any practical reason to use this instead of [9000's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9470845/344821)? Probably not; it's basically the same algorithm.

Comment: I also considered something along these lines, using pure iteration to compute a catamorphism :) But I could not invent an FP-esque solution which is not long and would not require pattern matching. Alas, this is missing from Python.

Comment: The try/except block in `rangestr()` can be replaced by `for end in iterable: pass`.  Also note that `iterable.next()` should be written as `next(iterable)` starting in Python 2.6.

Comment: Good point, the for loop is nicer -- I switched to that. And I do know about next() but didn't use it because there's still a lot of 2.5 users out there.

Answer (score 2):

Since 9000 beat me to it, I'll just post the second part of the code, that prints pcre-like ranges from the previously computed `output` plus the added type check:

```
for i in output:
    if not isinstance(i, int) or i < 0:
        raise Exception("Only positive ints accepted in pcre_ranges")
result = [ str(x[0]) if x[0] == x[1] else '%s-%s' % (x[0], x[1]) for x in output ]
print result
```

Output: `['1-3', '5-9', '20-23', '50']`

Comment: Thanks! `50-50` should just be `50`, though. Any easy solutions for that?

Answer (score 2):

Let's try generators!

```
# ignore duplicate values
l = sorted( set( [5,7,9,8,6, 21,20, 3,2,1, 22,23, 50] ) )

# get the value differences 
d = (i2-i1 for i1,i2 in zip(l,l[1:]))

# get the gap indices
gaps = (i for i,e in enumerate(d) if e != 1)

# get the range boundaries
def get_ranges(gaps, l):
  last_idx = -1
  for i in gaps:
    yield (last_idx+1, i)
    last_idx = i
  yield (last_idx+1,len(l)-1)

# make a list of strings in the requested format (thanks Frg!)
ranges = [ "%s-%s" % (l[i1],l[i2]) if i1!=i2 else str(l[i1]) \
  for i1,i2 in get_ranges(gaps, l) ]
```

This has become rather scary, I think :)